# "Fetch as Google" renders all pages to look like my homepage

Tags: render, fetch

I am trying to figure out why [my website's](http://smleimberg.com) posts and pages such as [my resume](http://smleimberg.com/steven-leimberg/) are getting a "Complete" status with a green check mark (seemingly no errors or redirects) when fetching and rendering as google, but all of them "render" and look like my homepage. The page speed insights tool seems to be using the same rendering engine as it seems to have [the same issue](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=smleimberg.com%2Fsteven-leimberg%2F&tab=mobile).

**Notes:**

The html served from my website on initial page load is the correct HTML and content. No redirects occur. The initial page load does not fetch content via JS. I mention this because although my website is **not** a one page application (I'm using Wordpress), I do use ajax in combination with a post variable flag to fetch new page content when the user navigates to the next page (after the initial page load).

I have verified that all of my pages have been indexed using the "site:" trick in Google search. They are indexed properly, but they aren't "rendering" properly.

Should I be worried? Should I just ignore that the pages aren't rendering properly? It doesn't make any sense. Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your resume page has a response type of content-type image/gif so google thinks that the page is an image??

Comment: Google search console reports that it sees it as "Content-Type: text/html;", and when I inspect the HTML resource in Chrome. Where are you seeing this?